# Prevent the file path of an image appearing above the image when using \begin{figure} \includegraphics{filepath}

Tags: graphics

I have inserted an image in my LaTeX document and the image always displays with the file path of the image directly above it.  How can I prevent this file path from displaying?

I am inserting the image like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics{C:/Users/Name/Pictures/image1.png}
\caption{a caption}
\label{fig:reference}
\end{figure}
```

Here is a working example of document that produces this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{C:/Users/Name/Pictures/image 1.png}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The image was inserted using the TeXnicCenter Insert>Picture function.

When I generate the pdf document, directly above any image (I have inserted multiple images using this technique) the file path displays above the image, in the case above it would show: "file\path\of\image", how can I prevent this from displaying?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You're probably loading some package or using some option that causes this behaviour.

Comment: This is caused by the `draft` option, either for the `graphicx` package or the class.

Comment: Is `file\path\of\image` meant to be a normal path or really three macros? You need to use `/` not `\` even under MS Windows, AFAIK.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry it is just meant to be an imaginary file path.  I will update the question to better reflect this.

Comment: Can you post the log you get for your example: it is fine for me. By the way, it's not a good idea to provide the `pdftex` option for the `graphicx` package. Unless you are using dvipdfmx, `graphicx` will pick up automatically on the correct driver.

Comment: I don't get the file name displayed. Which LaTeX compiler are you using (e.g. `pdflatex`)? Note that it isn't a good idea to pass the `pdftex` option directly to `graphicx`. It can detect the correct driver by itself most the time and you cause issues if you provide the wrong one.

Comment: @Joseph: The log itself is quite big, is there a specific part you need from it?  Or should I post the whole thing? I have removed the pdftex driver but still get the behaviour.

Comment: @Aesir In the first instance, try to cut down the example as much as possible (for example, do you need all of the packages you've loaded in order to see the issue?). Once you've done that, then the complete log would be useful as it's far from clear what is up.

Comment: This, as far as I know (not being a Windows user myself), can be caused by spaces in the path, for example in `Name`. Try enclosing the path in double quotes: `"C:/Users/.../image"`.

Comment: There are spaces in the file path, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Aesir Right, you've got both an absolute path and a space. These are both Bad Things. Try loading the package `grffile` to deal with the space issue. I'd also modify the path to be relative to the location of your `.tex` file.

Comment: @Aesit: Load the package [`grrfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Avoid special characters (blank spaces, underscores, …) in the name and the path of the file. For extended file name processing try the [grffile](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package from the [oberdiek](http://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek) bundle.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everybody.  Loading the package grffile has sorted the problem!

Answer (score 7):

Normally you shouldn't use white spaces or special characters in path. To use them you can load the package [`grffile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/grffile)

Alternatively you can use:

```
\includegraphics[]{\string"path"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another common reason for the same problem is one may use "**draft**" mode.

For example,

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,11pt]{report}
```

Simply removing the draft option will solve the problem.

Comment: (+1) Joined to upvote. I had added `draft` into the options without even knowing what it will do.