# Extra unwanted text "image.jpg" precedes image when using \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent the file path of an image appearing above the image when using \begin{figure} \includegraphics{filepath}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29438/prevent-the-file-path-of-an-image-appearing-above-the-image-when-using-beginfi)

I have the unwanted text "image.jpg" preceding image when using `\includegraphics`
The image appears with "image.jpg" text in front of it. 
Here's the code:

```
\includegraphics [scale=0.5] {polytope image.jpg}
```

How can I eliminate this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Avoid spaces in names.

Comment: or use `\includegraphics [scale=0.5] {{polytope image}.jpg}`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid blanks in the file name. TeXt does not like them.

Comment: It's TeX, not TeXt.